# Cant Connect to remote mysql server host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Ive looked all over for this one... Ive tried creating a new user, granting full priv on any ip, verified that they are there, restarted mysql server/ the server host, tried different clients on different machines. I really can't think of anything else to try. So far, I used this on root:
`GRANT ALL ON my_database.* TO my_user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';` 
Then checked `show grants for 'root'@'%'` which shows 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*ACE0FA0C29A21972F42BD2E7805A0D01C7126EC3' WITH GRANT OPTION`
Always getting the same error,

```
   ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL
   server
```

I also checked the firewall and that does not appear to be an issue. All the hosts are on the same local network. I have tried connecting via a public domain name and also direct local IP.

The server is on Windows 7 and I have tried connecting with clients on debian and OSX. I have no idea what is wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Don't forget to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after creating or editing an user.

Comment: did you set `bind-address` in your config file?

Comment: Yea, tried both of those still same error